# Composition of regulated functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

A function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a *regulated function,* if for all $t \in [a,b)$ the right-sided limit $\lim_{x \to t^+} f(x)$ exists and for all $t \in (a,b]$ the left-sided limit $\lim_{x \to t^-} f(x)$ exists.

Consider two regulated functions $f,g:[0,1] \to [0,1]$. When is the composition $g \circ f$ again a regulated function on $[0,1]$? 
If $g$ is continuous then for all $t \in [0,1)$ we have
$$\lim_{x \to t^+} (g \circ f)(x) = \lim_{x \to t^+} g(f(x)) = g\left(\lim_{x \to t^+} f(x) \right) = g(L) \in [0,1]$$
where $L := \lim_{x \to t^+} f(x)$ exists since $f$ is a regulated function on $[0,1]$. The same argument holds for the left-sided limit.

Now, what happens if we don't restrict ourselves to continuous functions $g$? I've found the following counterexample in which $f$ is continuous but $g$ is not:

$$f(x) := \begin{cases}0 &x = 0\\ x sin(\frac{1}{x})\ &0 < x \leq 1 \end{cases} \qquad  \mbox{and} \qquad g(x) := sgn(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0\\ 0 & x =0\\ -1 &x <0 \end{cases}$$

In this example the limit at $0$ does not exist. However, both functions take values outside of $[0,1]$ and I haven't been able to tailor the example to my situation. Is there some clever way to modify this example for regulated functions on $[0,1]$ or maybe different counterexample all together?

**EDIT**: Thanks to Rob's suggestion I was able to adjust the counterexample with the transformation $\phi(s) = \frac{s+1}{2}$. The transformed functions $F(x) := \phi(f(x))$ and $G(x) := \phi(g(x))$ are as follows:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} &x = 0\\ \frac{1}{2}\left(x sin(\frac{1}{x}) + 1\right)\ &0 < x \leq 1 \end{cases} \qquad  \mbox{and} \qquad G(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0\\ \frac{1}{2} & x =0\\ 0 &x <0 \end{cases}$$

Unfortunately, the two sequences which I used before to show that the limit at $x = 0$ doesn't exist don't seem to work any longer: $x_n := \frac{1}{\pi n}$ and $y_n := \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n \right)^{-1}$. I guess I have to find new ones.

**EDIT2:** Apparently this is a futile endeavor. As far as I understand the problem I have to show that the right-sided limit at $x = 0$ for the composition $G \circ F$ doesn't exist. One way to do this is to find two sequences, such that the limits under $(G \circ F)$ of these sequences are unequal. This approach works for the original functions $f$ and $g$ and the sequences as stated above. However, this plot of $F$ shows that there is no sequence, such that $F(x_n) = 0$ and thus $G$ will always evaluate to $1$. It's no longer a counterexample. Can anyone help me further? [image]

Comment: Your example works for $x, f(x), g(x) \in [-1, 1]$ doesn't it? So you should be able to use a linear mapping from $[0, 1]$ to $[-1, 1]$ and its inverse to transform your example into one where $x, f(x), g(x) \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: So you're saying I can just use $\phi(x) = \frac{x+1}{2}$ to map $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$? Let me think about that...